# Stackoverflow API getting answers in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I'm trying to use the stackoverflow API and I want to get answers of a question in a php array. So far here is my php code:

```
<?php


//KEY
$string = "key=my_key";

//Call stack API .$string
$stack_url = "compress.zlib://http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions";

//Get and Store API results into a variable
$result = file_get_contents($stack_url);
$jsonArray = json_decode($result);
print_r($jsonArray);
//echo($jsonArray->questions[0]->question_answers_url);
//var_dump($jsonArray);


?>
```

I want to store the answers of a question in an array called answers so that I can access them with a for loop.

The answer i get is :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [total] => 2618591
    [page] => 1
    [pagesize] => 30
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => c#
                            [1] => ssh
                            [2] => openssh
                            [3] => rsacryptoserviceprovider
                        )

                    [answer_count] => 1
                    [favorite_count] => 0
                    [question_timeline_url] => /questions/9164203/timeline
                    [question_comments_url] => /questions/9164203/comments
                    [question_answers_url] => /questions/9164203/answers
                    [question_id] => 9164203
                    [owner] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [user_id] => 311966
                            [user_type] => registered
                            [display_name] => simonc
                            [reputation] => 301
                            [email_hash] => 021f3344004f0c886d715314fa02037d
                        )

                    [creation_date] => 1328548627
                    [last_edit_date] => 1328611688
                    [last_activity_date] => 1328611688
                    [up_vote_count] => 0
                    [down_vote_count] => 0
                    [view_count] => 25
                    [score] => 0
                    [community_owned] => 
                    [title] => Format of PKCS private keys
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => c#
                            [1] => .net
                            [2] => combobox
                        )

                    [answer_count] => 3
                    [favorite_count] => 0
                    [question_timeline_url] => /questions/9174765/timeline
                    [question_comments_url] => /questions/9174765/comments
                    [question_answers_url] => /questions/9174765/answers
                    [question_id] => 9174765
                    [owner] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [user_id] => 1194399
                            [user_type] => registered
                            [display_name] => Goxy
                            [reputation] => 1
                            [email_hash] => 5fc8c96b6b85c6339cb9ac4ab60cb247
                        )

                    [creation_date] => 1328611202
                    [last_activity_date] => 1328611686
                    [up_vote_count] => 0
                    [down_vote_count] => 0
                    [view_count] => 15
                    [score] => 0
                    [community_owned] => 
                    [title] => WPF: Bind simple List<myClass> to Combobox
                )
....
```

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) has an optional parameter so using `$jsonArray = json_decode($result,true);` would return it as an associative array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly which property you want to extract, but I assume it's the 'question_answers_url'.

```
$answersArray = Array();
for($i=0;$i<count($jsonArray['questions']);$i++){
    //assuming it is the 'question_answers_url' property that you want
    array_push($answersArray,$jsonArray['questions'][$i]['question_answers_url']);
}
```

Ought to do it.

Comment: yes my problem is that this command gives me the url of the answers not the answers it self in an array.I want to get the answers in plain text format in an array. e.g $answersArray=[answer1_in_plain_text,answer2_in_plain_text,....]

Comment: check this bit of the api for what you need: [link](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/answers-by-ids)

Comment: ok i've checked api commands but don't know how to use the id value